# Testing 3-way switch which was converted to 2-way by wiring in basic switch

Tags: electrical, switch, multiway-switch

I have a smart light switch (Lutron Caseta model PD-6ANS) which was installed on a 3-way circuit with the other end supposedly wired so that it functions as a single non-3-way switch (this is because this smart switch does 3-way with a battery-powered wireless remote on the far end).

The lights that are controlled by this are not working and the contractor who installed it claims that it might be that the switch is defective so said I'd need to test with a regular switch and see if that works.  I bought one but when I opened up the current switch box there are a lot of wires coming from the smart switch and I'm not sure how to wire this basic one in.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  I've included pictures of both ends below.

Smart Switch
[image]

Other end of 3-way circuit
[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with photos looking squarely into the backs of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Do a credit card chargeback.  Contractors don't get to walk away from problems like that, and they should never have left the building without positively confirming it worked.  You are entitled to call them back and make them finish.  Is this Taskrabbit or other informal handyman service?

Comment: Are you sure about that battery-powered remote? That sounds really weird.  I'm accustomed to seeing a red-wire signal lead between the two switches, which allows the remote to communicate with the main switch.    In any case I fail to see how  a 2-way switch at the far end can support 3-way action. There's no such electric pathway.